# delete user and photo from directory

Tags: node.js

i want to delete user and his photo from directory si i have made this method , it delete the user but the photo still in the directory ,

```
export function deleteUser(req, res, next) {
    userModel.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
        if (err) next(err)
        else {
            const filename = user.photo.split('/images/')[1]
            fs.unlink(`images/${filename}`, () => {
                res.status(200).json({ message: 'Deleted!' })
            })
        }
    })
}
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: "what's my problem here ?" — Maybe if you paid attention to the error argument to the `unlink` callback in the same way you to for the `findByIdAndRemove` callback then your code would tell you.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.unlink` might also throw an error, but you're not handling it currently. You would send the `200` response even if there's an error.

Try this:

```js
fs.unlink(`images/${filename}`, (err) => {
  if (err) next(err)
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Deleted!' })
})
```

Comment: same problem , it remove the user without photo